Value of Cell D4 disappear if any cell in Column A that has the same value in Column B as D4 is marked as true
I'm trying to create a list that will compile ingredients from different recipes into a list of the total ingredients needed, but exclude ones from recipes that have already been made. I know how to do a table to total the amounts of each kind of ingredient, but I want to be able to check recipes as completed so that their ingredients aren't added to that list. So far, this is what I've been working with to try and wrangle some formula out of it:




A
B
C
D




1
Completed
Recipe
Ingredients
Amount


2
[ ]
Spaghetti
Noodle
20


3
[ ]
Spaghetti
Sauce
8


4
[ ]
Spaghetti
Cheese
2


5
[ ]
Spaghetti
Meatball
5


6
[ ]
Ramen
Noodle
25


7
[ ]
Ramen
Broth
14


8
[ ]
Ramen
Green Onion
6



Since this will be rolled out to other people, I'm going to format it and lock it so it will ultimately look like this:




A
B
C
D




1
Completed
Recipe
Ingredients
Amount


2
[ ]
Spaghetti
Noodle
20


3


Sauce
8


4


Cheese
2


5


Meatball
5


6
[ ]
Ramen
Noodle
25


7


Broth
14


8


Green Onion
6



I started going at it with just locking the "A" cell in the formula and dragging down for every amount in that recipe
D4 =if((TRUE=A$2),"",2)

but I have probably 100 on the list all with varying number of ingredients/amounts of each ingredient so ideally there's something that could help not have to do that?
Ultimately I want the value of cell D4 to disappear if any cell in Column A that has the same value in Column B as D4 is marked as true, but in a way that can be dragged to copy into every cell in the column and doesn't have to be changed for each set of recipes.

The requirements in your last paragraph don't make sense because column D is a numeric value, rather than TRUE or FALSE and because it appears that columns A and B won't have values in common, according to your table examples. Can you revise to clarify?

When every recipe is written out, I'm going to have the numbers in column D in a pivot table to say how many of each type of ingredient there is total. So the initial table will say that I need 45 noodle, but if I check off the box next to spaghetti it will say I need 25.

My first formula was just in column D for all D cells for the same recipe reference the first row of that recipe, but it would have to be edited for every different recipe. My thought process is that by adding the name of the recipe on every row I can somehow have a formula in column a or b (or other if needed) that if a cell in column B says "Spaghetti" and the cell next to it in A is true, then every cell in A that says spaghetti next to it will say true. Then for the D column it only needs to reference the A cell in that row to see if it's true, and can be dragged down for the whole list.

Consider a two table strucure. One table is a master table with just recipe and completed (using a checkbox) columns. Your child table is the first table you provided. Use XLOOKUP() in child table  column A to return the checkbox value from the master table. Use conditional formatting to white out font in child column D if column A value is TRUE.

To achieve the desired functionality, you can use a combination of conditional formatting and a formula.
Conditional Formatting:

Select the entire range of cells in Column D where you want the values to disappear.

Go to the "Home" tab and click on "Conditional Formatting".

Choose "New Rule".

In the "New Formatting Rule" dialog box, select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format".

In the formula bar, enter the following formula:
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,TRUE,$B:$B,$B4)>0


Click on the "Format" button and choose the desired format for the cells that meet the condition (e.g., white font color with white background).

Click "OK" to apply the conditional formatting.


Formula:

In cell D4, enter the following formula and drag it down to other cells in Column D:
=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A,TRUE,$B:$B,$B4)>0,"",C4)



Explanation:

The conditional formatting rule checks if there is at least one cell in Column A that is marked as true (i.e., has a checkmark) and has the same value in Column B as the current cell in Column D. If so, it applies the specified formatting, making the value in Column D appear blank.
The formula in Column D checks the same condition using the COUNTIFS function. If the condition is true, it returns an empty string (""); otherwise, it returns the value from Column C (the ingredient amount).

This combined approach ensures that the value in Column D disappears if any corresponding recipe in Column A is marked as completed, and the formula automatically updates as you add more recipes to the list.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
